# Galaxy S3 Mini does not turn screen off anymore

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen

Over a month ago, my Galaxy S3 Mini started having problems. It doesn't turn its screen off anymore even if I press power button.

Also, the pop-up menu appears suddenly a thousand times a day.

I also checked that there is no new firmware available.

Comment: Did you install any app before that happened? (maybe a pirated app)

Comment: 1) What pop-up menu? 2) Have you disabled screen lock? 3) As @geffchang said have you pirated any apps, when did this start?

Comment: Hi Guys I've no pirate app installed. There were few games which were all installed through Google Play. It could be a harware fault. However I'm not reliant to change stock rom to a custom one.

Comment: If it's still under warranty, it might be better to send it to customer service. :)